# Implementing a delete feature on a list in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I followed [this document](https://programmingwithswift.com/delete-list-item-with-swiftui/) (and [this one](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-delete-rows-from-a-list)) to add a *delete* feature to my list in an app using `SwiftUI`. Both pages say that once you add the *.onDelete(perform: ...)* piece of code you will be able to swipe and get a *Delete* button. Nevertheless this is not what I see. The code compiles but I see nothing on swipe.

My list is backed up by code like this:

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: ...,
    sortDescriptors: []
) var myList: FetchedResults<MyEntity>
```

and not by *@State*. Could this be an issue?

Below follows more of the relevant code, in case this may be useful:

```
private func deleteSpot(at index: IndexSet) {
    print(#function)
}

.........

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(self.myList, id: \.self.name) { item in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingDestinList.toggle()
                    .....
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(item.name!, forKey: "LocSpot")
                }) {
                    item.name.map(Text.init)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.onDelete(perform: deleteSpot)
    }
```

Comment: Minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Asperi, I just added some relevant code in the post, hoping this may be of some use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *delete on swipe* for dynamic container works only in `List`, so make

```
var body: some View {
    List {              // << here !!
        ForEach(self.myList, id: \.self.name) { item in
            HStack {

              // ... other code

            }
        }.onDelete(perform: deleteSpot)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Indeed you are right. I just found the same answer after losing quite a bit of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By searching and trying various options, I ended up by finding the issue.
I find the solution somewhat ridiculous, but to avoid other people to lose time, here it is:

The last part of the code in the post needs to be modified like the following in order to work.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List {
        ForEach(self.myList, id: \.self.name) { item in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingDestinList.toggle()
                    .....
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(item.name!, forKey: "LocSpot")
                }) {
                    item.name.map(Text.init)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.onDelete(perform: deleteSpot)
      }
    }
```